# Website Admin Rights: Database vs. File Structure

Tags: mysql, database, file, data-structures

**Background:**

I am making a website where I want modular administrative rights for read/write/edit priviledges.  My intent is to allow for any number of access level types, and to base it off of folder structure.

As an example, root admins would have read/write/edit for all site pages.  Group A may have read/write/edit to all files in the path www.example.com/section1/  (including subfolders), Group B would have read/write/edit to all files in www.example.com/section2/, and so on.

I have considered two options to impliment this:  create a MySQL database that would hold:

Group Name   (reference name for the access group)
Read         (list of folders the group can read separated by comma)
Write        (list of folders the group can write new content to separated by comma)
Edit         (list of folders the group can change already existing information separated by comma)

The other option I considered is creating a 'GroupAccess.txt' file somewhere and hand-jamming the information into that to reference.

**Question:**  What are the advanatages of each of these systems?  Specifically, what do I gain from putting admin access information in a database versus a text file, and vice versa?  (i'm looking for information on potential speed issues, ease of maintainability, ease of editing/changing the information that will be stored)

Note:  I'm not looking for a 'which is better', I want to know specific advantages so I can make a better informed decision on what's best for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that the database would be more secure over a text file for the simple reason a text file can be read over the internet as most web servers serve .txt file by default, this would allow for users with restricted access and non-users of the site to see the whole structure of you site and in turn can make you more open to possible attacks on certain areas of your site.

Another benefit of using a database is that you can easily use a join to check is a user has access to some content in the database where as with a file you'll need to read the file get the permissions and the go build the SQL and get the data from the database.

Those are just two of the things that have stuck out from reading your question, hope it helps.

Comment: decided to go ahead and use the db for it.  structure i'm using is just a separate table with access level names, along with all the site sections it can read/write/edit, then it'll check that with the user's admin level